# Substantial difference between ALB response time and Newrelic Web Response Time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gunicorn, newrelic, aws-application-load-balancer

I see a substantial gap of around 80 - 100 ms in the response time if I compare Target response time of load balancer and Web transaction time of Newrelic.

The request follows a path from the client on the same VPC to the load balancer (Application LB) to the instances which run on Gunicorn (19.9.0) and Flask.

On Newrelic I see an avg response time of 125ms while on Load Balancer I see it to be 200ms. This value gap is substantial.  Wondering if someone has faced this before and know why the difference is there

Number of instances behind the LB is 2, the request is not much around 150 queries per minute at peak

Comment: Are you saying the TargetResponseTime metric is higher? How is your ALB setup, is everything within one VPC?

Comment: Yes everything in the same VPC, Yes I am talking about TargetResponseTime

Setup: 
Client -> ALB  -> Webserver (2)

ALB is having a single target group